# average behavior of different data sets

Tags: distributions, mean, power-law

I have $n=100$ different data sets, each of which are distributed as what it seems to be a power-law distribution with different exponents, i.e. $x^{-\gamma_{i}}$ for distribution $i$. What I am interested in is the average distribution of all of these data sets.

The first solution that came to my mind is to find the power-law exponent for each of these distributions and find the average value for them. I would also like to have a distribution that would resemble as the average of these n distributions. In short I want to have a distribution that mimics the average of all these distributions and also find its exponent. (if it turned out to be power-law if not whatever the function is.)

Apologies if this is a trivial question, I did not even know where to look for an answer or hint. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Powerless can be tricky. "Power-laws have a well-defined mean only if the exponent exceeds 2 and have a finite variance only when the exponent exceeds 3" see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law

Comment: I am afraid my question was not clear. I am not looking for the mean and SD of a data set with PL distribution. I want to find the average power law exponent of different data sets.